# What are customs for eruv chatzerot in apartment buildings that also have gentiles as tenants

Tags: gentiles, real-estate, eruv-chatzerot, rental

Eruv chatzeirois:

I.e. 2 buildings with the same owner, and all Jews want to carry into the common (for both buildings) enclosed courtyard on Shabos

There are also non-Jewish tenants

1. Is it enough to rent the *reshus* (domain) i.e. from the super (employee of the owner, maybe considered like of the tenants) or the secretary of the managment office, or do I need to go to each tenant...?
2. How is this (renting of the *reshus*) done practically (what are the customs)?

I saw Shulchan Aruch [Orach Chaim 382](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01975_part_25.html#HtmpReportNum0140_L2)

Comment: For practical advice consult your rabbi.

Comment: @shmuel: I need to find a source, but we did rent from the Super, and simply gave her some candies. But this was many years ago and I hope I recall it properly.

Comment: Note that if you are in or near another Eruv (even if you don't hold of it because of Reshut HaRabbim issues) it's possible your buildings were already rented, eg. from the mayor, by them.

Comment: @DoubleAA if it is not in an area of an Eruv but in Brooklyn?

Comment: @DoubleAA this helps even if the Jew that rented is not in these buildings?

Comment: https://www.chabad.org/4051081/